# wp_send_json erase last value

Tags: php, ajax, json

I wish you can help me. 
I send data from php to Javascript with Json.

**PHP**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'evenements_filter_function'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'evenements_filter_function');


function evenements_filter_function(){ 
....
        $arrayTest[] = array(
        'name' =>$name,
        'address' => $address,

        );


    $my_json_str_test = json_encode($arrayTest);
    $params = array(
    'data' => $my_json_str_test
    );  
     wp_send_json($params);
}
```

**javaScript**

```
$('#filter_evenement').submit(function(){
jQuery.ajax({
            url:ajaxurl,
            dataType: 'json',
            data :"&action=myfilter",
            type:"GET", 
            success:function(data){console.log(data);
                var dataArray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);//parse JSON

            },
            fail: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {  
            }
        });
});
```

When I submit my form my Json value are always the same.
Is it not possible to update json data ?
I can only send one time ?
Because I tried to add an other wp_send_json($array) just after the other and json data are not updated.
How can I update json data send  ?

Thanks you :)

Comment: to modify datas, firstly you have to send them to the PHP script in "data" of the AJAX call. Then, in the PHP script, you read $_GET to get the datas.

Comment: I want to send data from PHP to Javascript by Ajax. My data to send is the array in "evenements_filter_function ". I send my data to Javascript and it's work but when I call an over time my function datas are the same. So Can I update value json ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify datatype in your AJAX call. Also, WP handles AJAX a bit differently, primarily:

```
$('#filter_evenement').submit(function(){
 jQuery.ajax({
        url:ajaxurl,
        type:"POST", 
        data : {action: "evenements_filter_function", val1: "value1", val2: "values2"},
        success:function(data){console.log(data);
            var dataArray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);//parse JSON

        },
        fail: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {  
        }
    });
 });
```

data has to contain `action` which specifies the WP AJAX handler function in the backend. You can also pass all values you need to send here (e.g `val1, val2`) Your `evenements_filter_function()` is not utilizing any data from AJAX call, it's just sending a response. But to access the values you'd check `$_POST['val1']`.